# Analyzing multiple data points per condition of a simulation model

Tags: regression, mixed-model, anova, simulation, independence

I wish to perform statistical analysis on a data set that is the result of running a simulation model.

I have simulated this model by varying five parameters, TA_PS, TA_IP, PA_PS, PA_IP, and PA_LGPP. All five parameters are categorical, the first 4 have three, and the last one has two levels. The outcome that I am interested in is a continuous variable named LGRD.

As the model contains randomness (the agents select and change their actions using some probability values), I simulate the model for each combination of these parameters 100 times, resulting in 100 LGRD values for each of the 162 conditions (3x3x3x3x2).

I want to analyze this data statistically to know which combinations result in higher LGRD values and how the LGRD changes with different levels of the parameters. Before this, I worked with a simple version of the model, one with just the TA_PS parameter. In that version, I detected a nonlinear link between LGRD and the levels of TA_PS in the form of an inverse U (the LGRD increased from level 1 to level 2, and then decreased from level 2 to level 3). Therefore, similar nonlinear links are also possible in this version of the model.

I am trying to understand what statistical method I should use to answer the above questions.

I think that to decide on the statistical method, I first need to understand the characteristics of my data. For example, should I treat the 100 data points of each combination as independent? Below you can see the data points corresponding to two of the 162 conditions I have tested:

[image]

[image]

These are the results of running the model over and over with fixed parameters, and the difference from run to run is due to the implemented probabilistic action selection. Does this make them dependent?

And what about the 162 conditions? These are the results of running the same model with different parameters, although with similarities. For example, conditions may differ in only the PA_LGPP level.

I first thought of using the mean of the 100 runs as a single outcome and then running a regression model with the parameter levels as the independent variables. However, this would reduce 100 values to one and seems like a waste of data!

I then thought of using a multi-way ANOVA but had trouble answering the above questions about independence...

I also searched mixed effect models and came up with a random intercept model with no predictors, where each of the 162 conditions with their 100 data points could have a different intercept indicating differences in LGRD. However, my knowledge of these models is scarce, and I don't know if such an approach will help me answer my research questions. Note that I am not looking for any trends in these 100 data points. These are just the results of running the model with the same parameters for 100 times to account for the randomness of involved processes.

Thanks in advance!